# If we don't allow duplicates, will we run out of questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

If we don't allow duplicate questions are we not stopping people from adding more a efficient solution to a problem than a previous excepted answer? And surely there can only be so many things that we can ask before we run out of questions? Don't take this the wrong way, and please do feel free to tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Technology moves on and there will always be new questions.

Comment: There will always be new languages, always new libraries. Plus what you are describing is "mission accomplished"

Comment: Duplicate questions are allowed but we mark them as such :)

Comment: Adding a new / better answer can always be done in the original question.

Comment: http://what-if.xkcd.com/34/ - Quoting the last line: *"140 characters may not seem like a lot, **but we will never run out of things to say.**"*

Comment: @Doktoro Reichard that's a brilliant article, thankyou

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are always more questions - new languages, libraries, etc will continue to appear. We are not at the apex of technological development. This will not slow down from here. This applies to all sites on the Stack Exchange network - there will always be new [games](http://arqade.com), there will always be new [movies](http://movies.stackexchange.com), etc.

Regarding adding more efficient solutions to a problem, closing a question as a duplicate doesn't prevent this. Duplicates are just that - duplicates, content already exists that answers the question.

This is the way that the Stack Exchange system is intended to work - one question defining the problem, with multiple answers as solutions to that question. The answers are then ranked according to their usefulness through the voting system. If there is a different method of achieving the same result this should be posted on the main question that the new question(s) were closed as a duplicate of, so that all of the useful information is stored in the same place rather than being scattered across a plethora of questions.

Comment: The idea that an "apex of technological development" even exists terrifies me

Answer (score 9):

We allow users to post new answers to old questions, even if there is an accepted answer. A more efficient solution is always welcome and would be up-voted over time by the community.

We will never run out of questions - there are so many different programming languages and tasks people are trying to achieve that we will always have a stream of novel questions flowing into the site.

And even if we did, I'm not sure what benefit duplicate questions would add. I wouldn't consider a site to be more "full" or fun to participate in if it contained two copies of every question. We inevitably receive duplicate questions on this site, but our practice is to close them as duplicates and (where appropriate) merge the answers together.

Comment: It does not sound that crazy. If a question was asked in 2009 and has 10 answers and you come with a 2014 solution, perhaps it should have it's own question

Comment: @mplungjan Unless the 2014 question differs from the 2009 question, the 2014 answer should always be posted in the 2009 question. We don't want duplicates. Now.. of course it doesn't always work that neatly, hence we have the vote-to-close as a duplicate option.

Comment: My issue with that, is the 2014 very well written question with the perfect 2014 answer but marked as duplicate. It is unlikely that people (other than me and some other OCDs at SO) will return to their answer, see the question they answer was deemed duplicate, COPY the accepted and brilliant answer into the possibly much less clearly asked and answered duplicate....

Comment: @mplungjan It is moderators who will merge answers together, if it seems appropriate. First the question must be closed as a duplicate and then, only if the questions really are 100% duplicates, a flag can be raised to ask a moderator to merge the answers. However, if you discover the 2009 question before you write your 2014 answer, don't create a new question just for the hell of it. Post an answer in the 2009 question instead.

Comment: Yes of course. I refer to the fact that I answer all questions from scratch since I have learned something new since last time I answered that question (somewhere, not necessarily at SO)